# I'd like to make my content area scroll over my fixed navigation bar, not under. How to?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

The website I'm building features a large background header image with a transparent fixed navigation bar on top. View it here: www.bedriftsdesign.no

Right now when you scroll the content scrolls over the header image just as planned, but when it reaches the navigation bar, I'd like it to disappear under the content, the same way the header background does, but it stays on top. To see the effect I'm trying to get, take a look here: http://www.googleventures.com/

Any idea on how to solve this? I've tried messing about with the z-indexes with no result yet.
Would be really grateful for some help.

Comment: I don't see the navbar below content...

Comment: What exactly did you do when you messed with the z-indexes? Could you give us some css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `<feature>` tag that holds all the content, the following css:

```
feature{
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Just needed to add it to my #content tag as well. Thanks a lot. It looks great now!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably put it as an answer if it worked for you :).

Comment: Just did it, didn't I? Accepted as answer.